# best practice for combining UI animation with async request?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, animation

I'm building a slot-machine game, the UI animation is easy to implement at first, but I find it hard to combine it with async request when I have to fetch the result from a backend service.

imagine that I have a slot machine module, I can use like this:

```js
import SlotMachine from './slot-machine';
const sm = new SlotMachine();
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // keep running for 5 seconds and display result as [1, 2, 3]
  sm.animateTo({
    duration: 5000,
    result: [1, 2, 3]
  });
});
```

so far so good, but when I want to fetch result from backend service, it would be something like this:

```js
import SlotMachine from './slot-machine';
const sm = new SlotMachine();
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  fetch('/api/getResult').then((result) => {
    sm.animateTo({
      duration: 5000,
      result: result
    });
  });
});
```

but the user experience is not so good in this implementation, after the user click the button, the animation won't start until the `fetch` request finish, it's even worse in slow network connection.

so I have to change my `slot-machine` api like this:

```js
import SlotMachine from './slot-machine';
const sm = new SlotMachine();
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const fakeStartTime = Date.now();
  sm.startFakeAnimation();
  fetch('/api/getResult').then((result) => {
    sm.stopFakeAnimation();
    const fakeEndTime = Date.now();
    sm.animateTo({
      duration: 5000 - (fakeEndTime - fakeStartTime),
      result: result
    });
  });
});
```

in this way, the user action will get response immediately, but, I don't think it's easy to implement the `startFakeAnimation` and `stopFakeAniamtion`, to make it feel seamless with the "true" animation.

Is there any better solution for this kind of problems ?

Comment: Rather than trying to get clever with fake animations, you could make the regular animation infinite so it handles a worse case scenario. You could have a separate timer that always tries to end the animation after 5s if you got a response from the service, otherwise it can keep animating. So only issues with network connectivity/poor connections should experience varying durations of animations.

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to have one set of animation handlers IMHO:

1. startAnimation
2. endAnimationWithResult

The problem with having to animate for a fixed time (five seconds in the above example) is that you never know how long the fetch call will take. Assuming that we have split the "animateTo" call into two calls ("start" and "endWithResult"), the remaining implementation would be fairly straightforward:

```
...
const startTime = Date.now()
sm.startAnimation()

const result = await fetch('/api/getResult')
const endTime = Date.now()
const delayTime = Math.max(5000 - (endTime - startTime), 0)  // Making sure we always spin for at least 5 sec
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayTime)) // Add delay to make sure we sping for at least 5 sec

sm.endAnimationWithResult(result)  // Stop spinning wheels and display the numbers
...
```

This way you wouldn't have to deal with synchronizing two animation sequences, plus the code becomes a lot more unit test friendly. Since the SlotMachine class already implements a fixed-length animation, breaking it into two methods should not be very difficult IMO.

Hope that helps!